# angularJs detecting click anywhere on page and updating model only in IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-9

I made a custom accordion template like so :

```
<div class="left_pane" ng-style="{height : mapStyle.height-82+'px'}">
            <div class="accord_main_wrap">
                <div class="accord_item_wrap" ng-repeat="head in heads">
                    <p class="accord_head" data-notvisible="true">{{head.text}}</p>
                    <div class="accord_content_wrap">
                        <ul>
                            <li ng-model="sub.text" ng-repeat="sub in head.subs">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sub.isChecked"/>
                                        <span class="accordSubs">{{sub.text}}</span>
                                    </label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have a model which has states of the checkbox.

The problem is that the first checkbox gets updated / toggles (true/false) when the user clicks anywhere on the page.

This behavior is only seen in IE9.
IE9 above are ok, FF and Chrome are ok.

I am at my wits end, Really need help.

**EDIT : Accompanying Model**

```
[{
    "id": "3",
    "text": "Main Title One",
    "subs": [{
        "id": "5",
        "text": "Sub Title One",
        "isChecked": false,
        "headId": "3",
        "headTitle": "Main Title One",
        "$$hashKey": "00E"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "text": "Main Title One",
        "isChecked": false,
        "headId": "3",
        "headTitle": "Sub Title Two",
        "$$hashKey": "00F"
    }],
    "$$hashKey": "004"
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "text": "Main Title Two",
    "subs": [{
        "id": "7",
        "text": "Sub Title One",
        "isChecked": false,
        "headId": "4",
        "headTitle": "Main Title Two",
        "$$hashKey": "00A"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "text": "Sub Title Two",
        "isChecked": false,
        "headId": "4",
        "headTitle": "Main Title Two",
        "$$hashKey": "00B"
    }],
    "$$hashKey": "005"
}]
```

Comment: There is not enough context here for us to help you out.  You would need to provide all of the javascript code in addition to any other templates you are using.  The best way is to actually provide a sample in jsfiddle or plunkr showing your problem

Comment: Added the accompanying model .This is the most I can give as there isnt much to explain. I am just watching the object using $watch and it fires when clicking on the whole page, not just a checkBox! No other code is present !